# Google Maps hashmap with LatLng

Tags: android, google-maps, nullpointerexception, hashmap

I have created one simple class which called MapMarker and it is the following:

```
public class MapMarker {
    private long id;
    private String resName;


    public MapMarker(){}

    public MapMarker(long id, String resName){
        this.id = id;
        this.resName = resName;
    }

    public long getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public String getResName(){
        return resName;
    }
}
```

while i am adding the markers in the google map i also create a HashMap in order when a infowindow is clicked i can start an activity with some parameters. The code i am using is the following for adding the markers and initilize the hashmap

```
private HashMap<LatLng, MapMarker> mapMarkersData = new HashMap<LatLng, MapMarker>();

markerCoords = new LatLng(lat, lng);

mapMarkersData.put(markerCoords, new MapMarker(markerId, markerRes));

map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(markerCoords).title(title).snippet("Click to see more info!"));
```

when i try to get the value from the hashmap i get a nullpointerexception. The code i am using is the following.

```
line 360:    markerId = mapMarkersData.get(marker.getPosition()).getId();
             markerResName = mapMarkersData.get(marker.getPosition()).getResName();
```

What is going wrong?

Edit:
the logcat is the following:

```
02-23 20:37:55.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4853): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-23 20:37:55.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4853): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-23 20:37:55.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4853):     at   .MapActivity.onInfoWindowClick   (MapActivity.java:360)
02-23 20:37:55.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4853):     at .GoogleMap$8.h(Unknown Source)
02-23 20:37:55.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4853):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.u$a.onTransact(Unknown Source)
02-23 20:37:55.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4853):     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:279)
02-23 20:37:55.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4853):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IOnInfoWindowClickListener$Stub$Proxy.onInfoWindowClick(IOnInfoWindowClickListener.java:82)
02-23 20:37:55.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4853):     at maps.y.bw.a(Unknown Source)
02-23 20:37:55.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4853):     at maps.a.y.f(Unknown Source)
02-23 20:37:55.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4853):     at maps.a.y.a(Unknown Source)
02-23 20:37:55.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4853):     at maps.a.bd.c(Unknown Source)
02-23 20:37:55.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4853):     at maps.a.dq.onSingleTapConfirmed(Unknown Source)
02-23 20:37:55.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4853):     at maps.e.v.onSingleTapConfirmed(Unknown Source)
02-23 20:37:55.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4853):     at maps.e.j.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
02-23 20:37:55.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4853):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-23 20:37:55.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4853):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-23 20:37:55.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4853):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
02-23 20:37:55.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4853):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 20:37:55.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4853):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-23 20:37:55.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4853):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
02-23 20:37:55.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4853):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
02-23 20:37:55.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4853):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Sorry one last edit has been made.

Comment: Post the logcat please and tell us the exact line where the NullPointer is occurring.

Comment: you are right. I have just edited my question. i Guess that for some reason the hashmap with the LatLng key doesn't return anything.

Comment: Hmmm... well just looking at the stack trace I'd say it's running into a null when you try to click on a marker and the map tries to create a popup window for. Is that what happens or do you get the NPE before you click on anything?

Comment: The code posted looks fine to me. Hard to tell. I'd recommend adding a breakpoint before the code thats failing. Lauch in debug mode, step though the code and check whats null while it shoudn't...

Comment: there where i say line 360 is inside the onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) so if i remove these two lines i don't get any error. I am not sure but there where i add the key LatLng to the hashmap for all the markers which should be unique and not changable, when i try to get the value i get a nullpointer exception. this is what i guess it happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the key is present in your HashMap.

I just had a similar problem in my code and I found that the lat/lng values I used for storing and lookup differed by their number of fractional digits, which caused the lookup to fail.

LatLng implements the equals(Object o) method, so you dont have to worry about referential equality issues.

Comment: I second this -- the `LatLng` you get out of a marker is not necessarily the same as the one you put into it. If you're going to use `LatLng`s as map keys, you should call `marker.getPosition()`, right after you add the marker to the app, and use the result as your key.